# How to cache a java applet?

Tags: java

can anyone explain to me how to cache a java applet, to speed up performance when reloading the same applet on another page or return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify parameters within the applet's HTML object or embed tag:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/applet_caching.html

Answer (score 1):

Does [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/applet_caching.html) answer it?

```
 <OBJECT ....>
     <PARAM NAME="archive" VALUE="...">
     ....
     <PARAM NAME="cache_option" VALUE="...">
     <PARAM NAME="cache_archive" VALUE="...">
     <PARAM NAME="cache_version" VALUE="...">
</OBJECT>
```

or

```
<EMBED ....
     archive="..."
     ....
     cache_option="..."
     cache_archive="..."
     cache_version="...">
```